# Downloading HTML source code with DownloadStringAsync doesn't download entire source on WP8

Tags: c#, .net, windows, windows-phone-8

I'm trying to download some HTML source code with DownloadStringAsync. My code looks like this:

```
    WebClient client = new WebClient();

    client.DownloadStringCompleted += 
    new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(DownloadStringCallback2);
    client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(url));

private void DownloadStringCallback2(Object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    source = (string)e.Result;
    if (!source.Contains("<!-- Inline markers start rendering here. -->"))
        MessageBox.Show("Nope");
    else
        MessageBox.Show("Worked");
}
```

If I look at the variable "source" I can see that some of the source is there, but not all. However, if I do something like this it works:

```
while (true)
        {
            source = wb.DownloadString(url);
            if (source.Contains("<!-- Inline markers start rendering here. -->"))
                break;
        }
```

Unfortunately I can't use that approach since WP8 don't have DownloadString.

Does anyone know how to fix this or if there is a better approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function should help you out

```
    public static Task<string> DownloadString(Uri url)
    {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();
        var wc = new WebClient();
        wc.DownloadStringCompleted += (s, e) =>
        {
            if (e.Error != null) tcs.TrySetException(e.Error);
            else if (e.Cancelled) tcs.TrySetCanceled();
            else tcs.TrySetResult(e.Result);
        };
        wc.DownloadStringAsync(url);
        return tcs.Task;
    }
```

Comment: Weird, that almost works. I do get a lot more of the source but still not everything. I'll check if the source that I get is enough for what I'm doing. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Worked like a charm! Tank you very much!